# Select data from 3 tables query

Tags: sql

My query is as below....

```
select * 
from UserMaster um 
inner join  ForumMaster fm on um.UserID = fm.UserID 
left join  
    (select * from CommentMaster cm) cmt on cmt.TopicID = @TopicID
```

My tables are as follows...

- `UserMaster` (`UserID, FName, LName`)
- `CommentMaster` (`CommentID, TopicID, Comment`)
- `ForumMaster` (`TopicID, UserID, Topic, DateCreated`)

and I want data from above three tables which is having same `TopicID`...

Comment: What do you mean by same TopicID ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * 
from UserMaster um 
    left outer join  ForumMaster fm on um.UserID = fm.UserID 
    left outer join  CommentMaster cm on cm.TopicId = fm.TopicId
where 
    cm.TopicId = @TopicId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM UserMaster um, CommentMaster cm, ForumMaster fm WHERE fm.UserID = um.UserID AND fm.TopicID = cm.TopicID
```

I am joining the tables without using join command.